# Rails undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I get the following error in Rails application. Can you help me?

I get an error when I connect two tables.
The user wants to use a table. I'm trying to manage the manager ID and user ID fields from a single table.

> ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
>
> Rails 5.2.2

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u29Mh.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJdVZ.png)

Database design and tables
**schema.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_24_160401) do

  create_table "projects", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "company"
    t.bigint "manager_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["manager_id"], name: "index_projects_on_manager_id"
  end

  create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "username", default: "", null: false
    t.string "fullname", default: ""
    t.bigint "manager"
    t.string "company", default: ""
    t.string "department", default: ""
    t.boolean "isadmin", default: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "projects", "users", column: "manager_id"
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :find_users, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit]
  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    end

    def find_users
      @users = User.all.order('created_at desc')
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Model files in model folder
**project.rb and user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

calling my code email column
**index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Projects</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Manager</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= project.name %></td>
        <td><%= project.description %></td>
        <td><%= project.company %></td>
        <td><%= project.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path %>
```

Comment: How looks your `Projects` controller?

Comment: resimag.com/p1/c7e6e3b5f41.png
resimag.com/p1/c541f8849df.png

Comment: Do you have tour associations in place?

Comment: It looks that some `Project` doesn't have `User`. To prevent of this situation I recommend use `validates :user_id, presence: true` in `Project` model.

Comment: There is no `user_id` column in your `projects` table but a `manager_id`. But at the same time, there is no `managers` table, but only a `users` table. You clearly do not follow Rails naming conventions and therefore must add more options to your association configuration (because of `manager_id` point to a foreign key on a `users` table). But even than you have to make a decision should this association be named `manager` (like in the model and the db) or `user` (link in your view). Please clarify!

Comment: users want to have a single table, 
managers have no tables,
yes I want to point a foreign key
users table id column = projects table manager_id column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Project` has a `manager_id`, but no table called `managers`, instead it's `users`. So in your relationship between projects and users, it needs to use the correct key.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, foreign_key: :manager_id
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :manager_id
end
```

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you.
I don't know how it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data is not well drafted in the schema. Is `User` the same thing as `Manager`? If it is not, you should have a `user_id` reference in the `Projects` table else, you'll have to add proper associations tying `manager_id` to `Users` then you can have `project.manager.email`

Comment: users want to have a single table, managers have no tables
users table id column = projects table manager_id column

Answer (score 0):

If user is optional for Project just call `project.user&.email`